# Is there default folder for UWP application?

Tags: file, uwp, directory, windows

For Windows application we have default folder, where .exe file is located. If we put some file to this folder we can open it in application, just specifying file name without path.

But for UWP, it's different. We have [KnownFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders), to which application has access. And I need specify in which KnowFolder my file is located.

But I want just put file to some location and open it from application, not specify folder type or folder path, the same way I use default folder for Windows application.

Is it possible?

Comment: What issue are you really trying to solve? Using relative paths is wrong, for desktop applications as much as for any other application type. You seem to be under the impression, that this made up *"default folder"* were the executable image used to create the process is located. This is not the case. You are referring to what is known as the *"current working directory"*. It can be set to point at any location when creating an application shortcut, or changed at runtime.

Comment: @IInspectable, I need to put xml file, which changes application settings (just for testing) and read it without path or other folder information.

Comment: Why are you obsessed with the *"without a path"* portion? What's so hard about constructing a fully qualified path? If you do need an executable-relative path, use the `ms-appx://` protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reason the installed folder is readonly so " just specifying file name without path" is not possible in UWP technology.

The recommend folder for your scenario is LocalFolder. Which is also the recommend storage place for settings, please have a look at official doc: [Store and retrieve app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data). Local folder is not complex, just a line of code:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

You can treat it as the default folder for your common data.

Comment: but where it is on the drive? C:\ProgramData? or C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local?

Comment: @Alexan It's the second path.You can test by output this folder when debugging. There is a localstate folder.